# how to fast find occurence in very large logs

Tags: linux, algorithm, logging

assume we have very large access logs with **IP** inside on machine with little RAM ( ~ 2 Mb ).

Task is to launch some utility ( perl preferable ) at the night, that can store IPs. At the morning we want answer the question in 1 second: "is there ip **a.b.c.d** in night logs ? "

- what structure of data we can use for this task ?
- what algorithm ?

Of course simple grepping logs will be very slow, this is not what we want.

Thank you !

Comment: Unless you want to create an indexing program which outperforms all previous indexing programs, tagging this as [tag:algorithm] seems overtly pompous.  In fact, this doesn't seem related to programming at all -- nominating to close as off-topic.  You might have better luck at https://askubuntu.com/ although software recommendations may be off-topic there as well

Answer (score -1):

You might want something like this:

https://papertrailapp.com/